# Herança multi-tabela no Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, herança

Tenho uma entidade `Resource`, que por sua vez tem várias implementações, por exemplo, `VideoResource` e `MarkdownResource`. `Resource` tem várias propriedades **compartilhadas**, os outros dois exemplos por sua vez, tem propriedades específicas para eles.

Eu já vi sobre herança usando `single-table`, mas acredito que não pode ser o meu caso, já que posso ter várias implementações de `Resource` e cada implementação pode ter de **2** a **5** ***propriedades específicas***.

Como fazer esse tipo de relação com `Eloquent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma que foi criado para trabalhar com esse tipo de relacionamento é [Polymorphic Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations), na pergunta só foi informado os nome das tabelas que é o suficiente para criar um exemplo minimo:

***Migration:***

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class TableVideoResources extends Migration
{    
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('videoresources', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title', 50);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('videoresources');
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class TableResources extends Migration
{    
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('resources', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 50);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('resourceable_id')->unsigned(); 
            $table->string('resourceable_type', 100);
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('resources');
    }
}
```

***Class Model:***

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Resource extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'resources';
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    public $timestamps = true;    

    public function resourceable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class VideoResource extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'videoresources';
    protected $fillable = ['title'];
    public $timestamps = true;    

    public function resource()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Resource::class, 'resourceable');
    }
}
```

ou seja, a classe `VideoResource` foi configurada para ter uma relação com `Resource`, dividindo ai os dados que são diferentes para `VideoResource` e as outras classes que herdam o que é igual devem ser configuradas igual `VideoResource` (na sua pergunta além de `VideoResource` tem `MarkdownResource`). Mas não existe muita mágica nisso tudo, por exemplo para salvar as relação deve criar primeiro `VideoResource` e acessar a relação e criar a `Resource`, exemplo:

*Gravando* `VideoResource`:

```
$videoResource = App\Models\VideoResource::create(['title' => 'Stackoverflow']);
```

*Gravando* `Resource` *pela relação:*

```
$videoResource->resource()->create(['name' => 'Portugues Brasil']);
```

*para recuperar as informações:*

```
App\Models\VideoResource::with('resource')->find(3);
```

*Saída:*

```
=> App\Models\VideoResource {#787                       
     id: 3,                                             
     title: "Stackoverflow",                            
     created_at: "2018-02-22 14:27:39",                 
     updated_at: "2018-02-22 14:27:39",                 
     resource: App\Models\Resource {#793                
       id: 3,                                           
       name: "Portugues Brasil",                        
       created_at: "2018-02-22 14:29:57",               
       updated_at: "2018-02-22 14:29:57",               
       resourceable_id: 3,                              
       resourceable_type: "App\Models\VideoResource",   
     },                                                 
   }
```

[se pode verificar tudo isso na documentação e nesse exemplo minimo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships).

***Referencias:***

- [Polymorphic Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)
- [What Are Polymorphic Relations and How Do We Use Them with Eloquent?](https://www.sitepoint.com/what-are-polymorphic-relations-and-how-do-we-use-them-with-eloquent/)

Comment: Eu até já tinha esquecido da pergunta, tentei resolver e consegui, exatamente da forma explicada. Aqui segue o repositório que implementa o problema já resolvido: https://github.com/lykeios-io/lykeios