# query with many-to-many polymorphic laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento, querybuilder

Eu tenho uma relação m-m polimorfica no meu banco onde:

> classe(id, nome)
>
> student(id, nome)
>
> lesson(id, nome)
>
> classeable(classe_id, classeable_id, classeable_type)

uma classe possui vários students e várias lessons.
um student pode estar em várias classes e assistir várias lessons
uma lesson pode estar em várias classes e ser assistida por vários students

Quando um aluno assiste uma lesson é gerado um resultado e nesses resultados eu quero incluir o nome da classe que o aluno participa pela qual ele assistiu à lesson. Não sei como buildar essa query no laravel usando essa estrutura de relacionamento no banco.

edit 1:

```
Classe extends model {

 public function students() {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Student::class, 'classeable');
    }


    public function lessons() {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Lesson::class, 'classeable');
    }
}
```

---

```
Student extends model {

    public function classes(){

        return $this->morphToMany(Classe::class, 'classeable');

    }
}
```

---

```
Lesson extends model {

    public function classes(){

        return $this->morphToMany(Classe::class, 'classeable');

    }
}
```

Comment: Se não sabe criar as relações ou você criou as relações?

Comment: no model Classe.php eu criei assim:
 public function students() {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Student::class, 'classeable');
    }


    public function lessons() {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Lesson::class, 'classeable');
    }

Comment: e nas classes students e lessons eu criei:

public function classes(){

        return $this->morphToMany(Classe::class, 'classeable');

    }

Comment: se poderia colocar o que você fez? porque quando se grava as informações o tipo da classe vai pela relação.

Comment: coloquei o edit 1

Comment: Você não entende como grava as informações?

Comment: eu não entendo como eu consigo recuperar a classe que possui um aluno x e uma lesson y. Não sei se tô conseguindo ser claro.

Comment: Então, parece que as relações estão corretas, para recuperar as informações é a mesma coisa tipo `$aluno = Student::find(1);` e `$aluno->classes()->get()`. não tem diferença como usar é do mesmo jeito que outra tipo de relação, será que é isso sua duvida?

Comment: Mais ou menos isso... É que assim, imagina que eu poderia ter feito essa relação com as tabelas classe_lesson (classe_id, lesson_id) e classe_student(classe_id, student_id). Aí pra eu recuperar a informação que eu quero eu poderia fazer um select na classe usando o join na classe_lesson (lesson_id) e outro join na classe_student (student_id). Só não sei fazer isso no laravel.

Comment: Ygor, nas relação ele já faz isso para você, de forma transparente, uma pergunta se testou o jeito que eu disse se sim o que aconteceu:?

Comment: Testei, ele me retorna uma lista de todas as classes do aluno

Comment: Talvez esteja salvando errado. como está salvando?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Herança multi-tabela no Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/277456/heran%c3%a7a-multi-tabela-no-laravel)