# Como mudar a palavra chave de relacionamento do laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou com o seguinte problema, entrei em um projeto onde o banco de dados já existia e está em produção, portanto todas as chaves estrangeiras deste banco estão com a nomenclatura `fk_` e o `Eloquent` do `Laravel`, relaciona as `models` com as tabelas a partir da palavra chave `_id`, será que é possível mudar dentro das configurações do `Laravel` a busca de `_id` para `fk_`?

Comment: Adriano, e ai deu uma clariada a resposta?

Comment: Siiimm!! Muito obrigado. entendi o que disse, tentarei aplicar. Obrigado

Comment: Se for útil pra você aceite como resposta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) é muito flexível nesse aspecto, como o banco de dados já existia e consequentemente não seguiu a mesma nomenclatura do `Laravel`, existe as formas de passar os nomes da chaves nas configurações, exemplos:

***Relacionamento 1:1***

Uma pessoa tem um endereço e um endereço pertence a uma pessoa:

```
class Peoples extends Model
{   
    //Relacionamento.
    public function address()
    {
        //     $this->hasOne(relacao, chave estrangeira, primary key);
        return $this->hasOne('App\Address', 'peopleid', 'id');
    }
}

class Address extends Model
{    

    //Relacionamento.
    public function people()
    {
        //     $this->belongsTo(relação, chave estrangeira local, primary key da relação);
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Peoples', 'peopleid', 'id');
    }
}
```

***Relacionamento 1:N***

Uma pessoa pode ter um ou vários telefones:

```
class Peoples extends Model
{   
    //Relacionamento
    public function phones()
    {
        //     $this->hasMany(relação, chave estrangeira da relação, primary key local);
        return $this->hasMany('App\Phones', 'peopleid', 'id');
    }

}

class Phones extends Model
{    
    //Relacionamento
    public function people()
    {
        //     $this->belongsTo(relação, chave estrangeira local, primary key da relação);
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Peoples', 'peopleid', 'id');
    }
}
```

***Relacionamento N:M***

Um autor pode ter vários livros e um livro pode ter vários autores, onde essa relação gera um tabela intermediária.

```
class Authors extends Model
{    

    //Relacionamento.
    public function books()
    {
        //    $this->belongsToMany('relacao', 
        //                         'nome da tabela pivot', 
        //                         'key ref. authors em pivot',  
        //                         'key ref. books em pivot')
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Books',
                                    'booksauthors', 
                                    'authorid', 
                                    'bookid');
    }
}

class Books extends Model
{    

    //Relacionamento.
    public function authors()
    {
        //    $this->belongsToMany('relacao', 
        //                         'nome da tabela pivot', 
        //                         'key ref. books em pivot', 
        //                         'key ref. author em pivot')
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Authors', 
                                    'booksauthors', 
                                    'bookid', 
                                    'authorid');
    }
}
```

Essas são as relações mais tradicionais (*talvez sofrendo alguma variação para algum modelo de banco*) e pode te ajudar a adequar o seu banco antigo, mas, além desses três existe alguns [outros tipos descrito na documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) que podem ser observados também.

Também já escrevi algumas respostas que pode utilizar como base:

- [Salvar relacionamento 1:1 no Laravel 5.3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175842/salvar-relacionamento-11-no-laravel-5-3)
- [Problemas com relacionamento um para muitos laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152089/problemas-com-relacionamento-um-para-muitos-laravel/152108#152108)
- [Como usar o relacionamento hasmany no laravel 5.2?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173966/como-usar-o-relacionamento-hasmany-no-laravel-5-2/173976#173976)
- [Laravel / Eloquent - Consulta em mais de uma tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244308/laravel-eloquent-consulta-em-mais-de-uma-tabela/244376#244376)
- [Salvar varios atributos para um mesmo objeto no Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168781/salvar-varios-atributos-para-um-mesmo-objeto-no-laravel)
- [Herança multi-tabela no Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/277456/heran%C3%A7a-multi-tabela-no-laravel/278100#278100)

***Referencias***

- [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)