# Como pegar dados de relacionamento hasMany

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Eu tenho uma tabela `Grupo` e uma `Topicos`, onde o grupo tem muitos tópicos e está assim meu código:

```
public function topicos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Topico');
}
```

No meu `Controller` está assim:

```
public function grupo($slug)
{
    $grupo = Grupo::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    return view('grupo', compact('grupo'));
}
```

No entanto, dessa maneira eu não consigo acessar acessar os dados das duas tabelas através de um único `foreach`, eu gostaria de pegar os dados assim:

```
$grupo->topicos->titulo
```

mas isso não funciona e ao invés de usar `first()` eu tenho que usar `get()` e depois fazer dois `foreach` pra poder pegar todos os dados.

O problema é que tem várias partes do código que eu preciso inserir apenas o id do grupo, e ter que fazer um `foreach` só pra isso me parece desnecessário.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu código e na sua pergunta tem explicitamente dito uma relação [1:N](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152089/problemas-com-relacionamento-um-para-muitos-laravel/152108#152108) (*um para muitos*), sendo que grupo tem vários tópicos e um tópico é de um grupo. No site tem várias explicação de como funciona essa relação, exemplo:

- [Problemas com relacionamento um para muitos laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152089/problemas-com-relacionamento-um-para-muitos-laravel/152108#152108)
- [Como usar o relacionamento hasmany no laravel 5.2?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173966/como-usar-o-relacionamento-hasmany-no-laravel-5-2/173976#173976)
- [Como mudar a palavra chave de relacionamento do laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/280694/como-mudar-a-palavra-chave-de-relacionamento-do-laravel/280784#280784)

sendo que o modo das suas configurações não estão presente como informações na sua pergunta e eu imagino que as suas configurações de relação estejam corretas:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Grupo extends Model
{        
    public function topicos()
    {        
        return $this->hasMany('App\Topico','grupo_id', 'id');
    }    
}
```

---

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Topico extends Model
{        
    public function grupo()
    {        
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Grupo','grupo_id', 'id');
    }    
}
```

esse exemplo de relação que imagino ser a sua.

Para buscar os items da relação de Grupo com Topicos:

```
$grupo = Grupo::with('topicos')->where('slug', $slug)->first();
```

terá os itens de grupo e na relação de tópicos uma coleção, e é assim que foi configurado, mas, se quiser trazer na relação apenas um tópico também dá (*eu entendi que você precisa trazer apenas um tópico achei isso estranho, mas, existe a possibilidade de fazer um filtro na relação e limitar o número de itens retornados*), exemplo:

```
$grupo = Grupo::with(['topicos' => function($query){$query->limit(1);}])
    ->where('slug', $slug)->first();
```

e para recuperar mesmo trazendo um item da coleção (que seria bom por causa do desempenho, por trazer só o que precisa):

```
{{ $grupo->topicos[0]->titulo }}
```

porque o que vale nisso tudo é a relação sendo que tópicos sempre gera uma lista, mas, com esse código acima restringe apenas um item a ser trazido na `SQL`.

***Observação:*** *também é bom lembrar que o carregamento adiantado feito com `with` é otimizado, gerando no caso duas* `SQL` *o contrário se for feito o carregamento em tempo de execução é ruim por gerar em cada interação uma instrução* `SQL` *para o banco de dados*.

Comment: é bem isso que precisava entender. No meu caso, eu preciso pegar todos os topicos de um grupo e exibir. É uma especia de forum de discusão. Mas sua explicação me fez compreender melhor o que estou fazendo. Muito obrigado